# Email validation issue in registration form magento 2

Tags: magento2

In Magento2 registration form when we insert email id then there is no exact validation for email like if you enter email: `john@test.demo.com` then it will accept and customer will able to register.
I tried to fix by jquery script and other ways but couldn't solve.

Please anybody have fixed issue as this issue exist in every version of Magento 2.

Answer (score 0):

I've quickly looked through the source code on GitHub to determine whether the customer registration form (`Magento_Customer::form/register.phtml`) properly applies a validation rule to the e-mail field, and it does (in the Magento 2.4-develop branch at least).

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/app/code/Magento/Customer/view/frontend/templates/form/register.phtml#L218

When I search for "validate-email" I was able to find two places where "validate-email" was associated with a regular expression.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/047f5b943cb74e5bac67360aaadae31e165c09db/app/code/Magento/Ui/view/base/web/js/lib/validation/rules.js#L441

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/a1aaf8f0eeae4cbc763c0ab4ca3b43a9cc250f18/lib/web/mage/validation.js#L622

Both seem to use the same regular expression so it doesn't really matter which one Magento actually uses in case of the customer registration form.

When I try this regular expression through Regex101 with the "ECMAScript" flavour I can verify that this regular expression seems to correctly validate a given string.

Apart from all of this, e-mails are allowed to be sent from and to a sub-domain as far as I know, so "john@test.demo.com" would be a valid e-mail. I tried to check and explain this more thoroughly than that so that I could verify that this isn't a bug in Magento.